# Trying to change the permissions of a symlink results in changing the permissions of its target

Tags: linux, shell, chown

I am trying to change the ownership of a symbolic link (`jakarta`) which points to another directory, but when I run

```
$ chown user1 jakarta
```

it changes the ownership of the directory that `jakarta` is pointing to instead. Why?

```
$ chown -h user1 jakarta
ownership of `jakarta' retained as user1
```

Comment: you can use the command using -v option and share the result with us. It contains whats many useful information(chown -v user1 jakarta

Comment: it's showing ownership of `jakarta' retained as user1 but again when i do ls -l jakarta it's showing root as the owner and group name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to change the ownership of a symbolic link, however, the permissions of the link itself don't matter - what mappers are the permissions of the target that the link points to. If you *do*, for whatever reason, want to change the ownership of the actual symlink you can use `chown -h`:

```
$ ll
total 4.0K
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    3 Mar 25 08:18 bar -> foo/
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4.0K Mar 25 08:18 foo/

$ chown -v quux:quux bar
changed ownership of `bar' from root:root to quux:quux
```

Note how it actually changed the target (`foo`):

```
$ ll
total 4.0K
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    3 Mar 25 08:18 bar -> foo/
drwxrwxr-x 2 quux quux 4.0K Mar 25 08:18 foo/

$ chown -vh quux:quux bar
changed ownership of `bar' from root:root to quux:quux

$ ll
total 4.0K
lrwxrwxrwx 1 quux quux    3 Mar 25 08:18 bar -> foo/
drwxrwxr-x 2 quux quux 4.0K Mar 25 08:18 foo/
```

Comment: +1 for chatching that the question is about the symlinks... ;) nice answer.